# Determine a network interface is ready

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

If I disable (`ip link set wlan0 down`), enable (`ip link set wlan0 up`) and run, for example, `iwlist wlan0 scan`, I've got an error saying that device or resource is busy (`wlan0      Interface doesn't support scanning : Device or resource busy`, it works if I wait a bit).

I'm trying to find when it's ready.
My current solution is to run `iwconfing wlan0 | grep "Link Quality" | wc -l`, if 0 it's not ready, 1 ready.
I'm looking for a less hacky way.

Comment: can you post the actual error message?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: 'Device and resource busy' and not 'Operation not permited', my bad

Comment: have you tried `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` ?

Comment: I'm logged as root